# Remove all non-numeric characters but keep a specific word

Tags: java, regex

I'm working on a script that can download mangas from [www.mangafox.me](http://mangafox.me) in Java.

Unfortunately, this website doesn't have any APIs thus I use some archaic ways to get my data. However, it's possible to get an xml with every chapters of a manga. For example : http://mangafox.me/rss/nisekoi.xml.

I parse this xml and use the `title` tag to get a chapter's number and associated volume.

For example, I have a string like this :
`Nisekoi Vol TBD Ch 215` and I want to keep only `TBD` and `215`.

At the moment, I replace all non-numeric characters with spaces and keep every occurences of `TBD` by using :

```
String title = "Nisekoi Vol TBD Ch 215";
title = title.replaceAll("[^0-9.\bTBD\b]+", " ").trim();
```

`title` equals to `"TBD 215"` and then I use `title.split(" ")` to get the volume and the chapter.

This is working just fine until I do the same with a manga that starts with an T. Apparently, the capital T isn't replaced by a space.

I'm not very good at Regular expression so how do I get to replace every character that is not a number, a dot (for decimals) or the word "TBD" by a space in Java ?

Thanks !

Comment: If I get you right, you're only interested in the number at the end of each title, right? You could go for [`\\d+$`](https://regex101.com/r/gA1zW9/1) then and do `TBD`+ `your_number` afterwards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("Vol ([A-Z]{3}) Ch (\\d{3})");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
if(matcher.find()){
  String volume = matcher.group(1);
  String chapter = matcher.group(2);
}
```

Comment: I tweaked a bit your solution and divided the matching in two pars (one for the volume and one for the chapter) as some chapters don't have a volume. `matcher.find()` in your example wouldn't return true. But thank you anyway, it's exactly what I needed :) !

Answer (score 1):

**KISS** - Keep it stupid simple: grab the number at the end of the title with [`\\d+$`](https://regex101.com/r/gA1zW9/1) and concenate your title afterwards like `TBD` + `your_number`.

Comment: Was about to post this solution. Might as well insert a code snippet for that.

Comment: @MuratK.: Go for it - I am not too familiar with `Java`.

Comment: Done. I also extended it for the literal char dot.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that "Vol" and "Ch" are the fixed parts here, so you could use this regex :

```
Vol (.*) Ch (.*)
```

and retrieve it's first group for the volume and its second for the chapter.

You can see the java code in action [here](https://ideone.com/2wKbhE).

FYI, you're having an error because you're using a character class (`[...]`) which means "any character of the following class" rather than "this sequence of characters".

Answer (score 0):

Without a regex, I'd try something like this:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(title.length());
for (int i = 0; i < title.length(); ++i) {
  char ch = title.charAt(i);
  if (ch == '.' || Character.isDigit(ch) {
    sb.append(ch);
  } else if (ch == 'T' && title.indexOf("TBD", i) == i) {
    sb.append("TBD");
    i += 2;
  }
}
title = sb.toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many answers here - so here is mine which extends the answer from Jan.

```
String title = "Nisekoi Vol TBD Ch 215.5";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[\\.\\d]+$");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(title);
   if (matcher.find())
   {
     System.out.println("TBD " + matcher.group(0));
   }
```

output is : `TBD 215.5`.

---

This will always match the numbers at the end of the string. So it does not matter what is leading the string. This will also match dots.